# Different encryption results between platforms, using OpenSSL

Tags: c, macos, encryption, openssl, aes

I'm working on a piece of cross-platform (Windows and Mac OS X) code in C that needs to encrypt / decrypt blobs using AES-256 with CBC and a blocksize of 128 bits. Among various libraries and APIs I've chosen OpenSSL.

This piece of code will then upload the blob using a multipart-form PUT to a server which then decrypts it using the same settings in .NET's crypto framework (Aes, CryptoStream, etc...).

The problem I'm facing is that the server decryption works fine when the local encryption is done on Windows but it fails when the encryption is done on Mac OS X - the server throws a "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed exception".

I've looked at this from many perspectives:

1. I verified that the transportation is correct - the byte array received on the server's decrypt method is exactly the same that is sent from Mac OS X and Windows
2. The actual content of the encrypted blob, for the same key, is different between Windows and Mac OS X. I tested this using a hardcoded key and run this patch on Windows and Mac OS X for the same blob
3. I'm sure the padding the correct, since it is taken care of by OpenSSL and since the same code works for Windows. Even so, I tried implementing the padding scheme **as it is in Microsoft's reference source for .NET** but still, no go
4. I verified that the IV is the same for Windows and Mac OS X (I thought maybe there was a problem with some of the special characters such as ETB that appear in the IV, but there wasn't)
5. I've tried LibreSSL and mbedtls, with no positive results. In mbedtls I also had to implement padding because, as far as I know, padding is the responsibility of the API's user
6. I've been at this problem for almost two weeks now and I'm starting to pull my (ever scarce) hair out

As a frame of reference, I'll post the C client's code for encrypting and the server's C# code for decrypting. Some minor details on the server side will be omitted (they don't interfere with the crypto code).

**Client:**

```
/*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
void
__setup_aes(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, const char *key, qvr_bool encrypt)
{
    static const char *iv = ""; /* for security reasons, the actual IV is omitted... */

    if (encrypt)
        EVP_EncryptInit(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), key, iv);
    else
        EVP_DecryptInit(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), key, iv);
}

/*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
void
__encrypt(void *buf,
    size_t buflen,
    const char *key,
    unsigned char **outbuf,
    size_t *outlen)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    int blocklen = 0;
    int finallen = 0;
    int remainder = 0;

    __setup_aes(&ctx, key, QVR_TRUE);

    EVP_CIPHER *c = ctx.cipher;
    blocklen = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size(&ctx);

    //*outbuf = (unsigned char *) malloc((buflen + blocklen - 1) / blocklen * blocklen);
    remainder = buflen % blocklen;
    *outlen = remainder == 0 ? buflen : buflen + blocklen - remainder;
    *outbuf = (unsigned char *) calloc(*outlen, sizeof(unsigned char));

    EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx, *outbuf, outlen, buf, buflen);
    EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(&ctx, *outbuf + *outlen, &finallen);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
    //*outlen += finallen;
}
```

**Server:**

```
static Byte[] Decrypt(byte[] input, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        try
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (input == null || input.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
            if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("iv");

            byte[] unprotected;


            using (var encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                encryptor.Key = key;
                encryptor.IV = iv;
                using (var msInput = new MemoryStream(input))
                {
                    msInput.Position = 0;
                    using (
                        var cs = new CryptoStream(msInput, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(),
                            CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    using (var data = new BinaryReader(cs))
                    using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
                        int bytes = 0;
                        while ((bytes = data.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) != 0)
                            outStream.Write(buf, 0, bytes);

                        return outStream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Does anyone have any clue as to why this could possibly be happening? For reference, this is the .NET method from Microsoft's reference source .sln that (I think) does the decryption: https://gist.github.com/Metaluim/fcf9a4f1012fdeb2a44f#file-rijndaelmanagedtransform-cs

Comment: Nice question. I also struggled with the same issue one year ago, looking forward for an answer on this.

Comment: I'd suggest sanity checking both the client's key and IV to make sure that they really are identical, dump them prior to encryption, including `EVP_CIPHER_iv_length()` and `EVP_CIPHER_key_length() ` (Mostly to ensure that you aren't using data past either the key or IV arrays). I'd also suggest checking using trivial values (e.g key and IV set to all 0, or all ~0)

Comment: I've run those sanity checks but haven't tried with a trivial IV, like an IV set to 0s. Will do it now.

Comment: You might also want to try decrypting it using the command line `openssl enc`. Also, you might as well use it to encrypt and check if you're getting the same results. (btw, my suspicion is that either the Windows or OS X build are using uninitialized data as part of the IV or key, leading to differing results. Hence my suggestions to check the key, the IV, and their lengths.)

Comment: I've set my IV to 0x30 ('0') and now it seems to obtain the same results for both platforms. Maybe this is indeed an encoding problem on my part. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: CBC mode provides confidentiality only, and you must add a MAC to use CBC mode safely. You should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Your calculation of `outLen` fails, PKCS#7 always pads, so you need to add 1 to 16 bytes to the size, not 0 to 15, i.e. it should always be `buflen + blocklen - remainder`

Comment: Your comment in the question: "I verified that the IV is the same for Windows and Mac OS X (I thought maybe there was a problem with some of the special characters such as ETB that appear in the IV, but there wasn't)" indicates a clear misunderstanding about how *encoding* works. If you ever treat ciphertext, key or IV as text, you need to perform encoding / decoding. If you don't then you may introduce errors outside the code you provided.

Comment: Yes, indeed in the end the encoding of the IV as well as the private key was also an issue - the server was using an encoding which I wasn't expecting.

Comment: Why is blocklen set to 0 when it is used in the % operation?  Couldn't this cause a problem? Shouldn't it be set to 16?

Comment: Note also that names that begin with two underscores such as `__setup_aes` and `__encrypt` are [reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3): "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use."

Comment: Useless now but: IVs aren't secret, and hiding one provides no security benefit. OTOH using the same IV, which the posted code suggests, for multiple encryptions with the same key hurts security (though for CBC not as badly as some other modes where it is catastrophic). Those are offtopic here, but have (both) been answered many times on crypto.SX and security.SX where they are ontopic.

Comment: Are you using a library?

Comment: You don't check any of your operations for errors. That's worrisome.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL version differences are messy. First I suggest you explicitly force and veryify the key lengths, keys, IVs and encryption modes on both sides. I don't see that in the code. Then I would suggest you decrypt on the server side without padding. This will *always* succeed, and then you can inspect the last block whether it is what you expect.

Do this with the Windows-Encryption and MacOS-Encryption variant and you will see a difference, most likely in the padding.

The outlen padding in the C++ code looks odd. Encrypting a 16 byte long plaintext results in 32 bytes of ciphertext, but you only provide a 16 byte long buffer. This will not work. You will write out of bounds. Maybe it works just by chance on Windows because of a more generous memory layout and fails on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

AES padding scheme has been changed between OpenSSL versions 0.9.8* and 1.0.1* (at least between 0.9.8r and 1.0.1j). If two of your modules uses these different versions of OpenSSL then this could be the reason for your problem. To verify this first check OpenSSL versions. If you hit the described case you may consider on aligning the padding scheme to be the same.